# Understanding protobuf import and output relative paths

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am fairly certain this is operator error and I am at the point I am not thinking clearly.

Here is the setup:

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto/a.proto
$GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service b>/proto/b.proto
```

etc.

Now in the proto file I am using imports similar to go (perhaps the issue) such that `a.proto` has:
`import "github.com/<company>/<service b>/b.proto"`

I have possibly two separate issues.

1. I cannot get the import to compile properly using `go:generate protoc`
2. I cannot get the output `a.pb.go` file to be placed in the `$GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto/` path.

I have attempted multiple configurations probably not in the correct combination.
`Using option go_package = "github.com/<company>/<service b>/proto"` in each `.proto` file

Multiple variations of go generate;

```
go:generate protoc --proto_path=.:$GOPATH/src --go_out=$GOPATH/src a.proto
go:generate protoc --proto_path=.:$GOPATH/src --go_out=. a.proto 
go:generate protoc --go_out=import_prefix=github.com/<company>/:. api.proto
```

I clearly have a poor understanding on how protoc looks at import paths and file outputs. Anyone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Update #1**
In a.proto;

```
option go_package = "github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto";

import "github.com/<company>/<service b>/proto/b.proto";
```

and the go generate;

```
//go:generate protoc --proto_path=$GOPATH/src --go_out=$GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto a.proto
```

Which is called from a go file in the proto directory with the a.proto.

I received the error;
a.proto: File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path ch encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).

I have confirmed $GOPATH is to the expected location.

**Solution**

Thanks to Shivam Jindal for pointing me in the correct direction. The import is exactly as described in his solution. The output was a problem of my misusing both --go_out and option go_package. I used the go_package to specify the output location and --go_out to specify the root similar to --proto_path. Now everything works.

```
option go_package = "github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto";
```

and

```
//go:generate protoc --proto_path=$GOPATH/src/ --go_out=$GOPATH/src/ $GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto/a.proto
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `option go_package` is not meant for other dependency import at all, it's the Go package name where the new proto bindings for Go `(a.pb.go file)` will be placed.

Now coming to the output file location, I can see you are using go-generate. Firstly it depends from which directory you are invoking that if the path used in `--go_out=` is relative path. I would say use absolute paths. If you want to put the output file in that location you mentioned, use `--go_out=$GOPATH/src/github.com/<company>/<service a>/proto/` in go-generate.

To correctly import the other file `b.proto` in your `a.proto` use the fully qualified import path as you have done. Just that use `--proto_path $GOPATH/src` in go-generate. Also please update the question with the errors you are seeing in case it does not work.

Please see [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#importing-definitions) for more information on import paths.